# Unable to use Tor

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

```
29-Jun-17 9:52:05 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 9:52:05 AM.400 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
29-Jun-17 9:58:08 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 9:58:08 AM.300 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "default" (was using "bridges") 
29-Jun-17 9:58:08 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 9:58:08 AM.300 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 9:58:08 AM.300 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 9:58:08 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
29-Jun-17 9:58:08 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
29-Jun-17 10:00:08 AM.900 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
29-Jun-17 10:04:32 AM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 10; recommendation warn; host B84F248233FEA90CAD439F292556A3139F6E1B82 at 85.248.227.164:9002) 
29-Jun-17 10:04:32 AM.300 [WARN] 9 connections have failed: 
29-Jun-17 10:04:32 AM.300 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:04:32 AM.300 [WARN]  3 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
29-Jun-17 10:04:32 AM.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host 74A910646BCEEFBCD2E874FC1DC997430F968145 at 199.254.238.52:443) 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
29-Jun-17 10:11:54 AM.800 [WARN]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
29-Jun-17 10:11:57 AM.300 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set. 
29-Jun-17 10:12:48 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:12:48 AM.600 [NOTICE] Switching to guard context "bridges" (was using "default") 
29-Jun-17 10:12:48 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:12:48 AM.600 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:12:48 AM.600 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:13:10 AM.200 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (Connection timed out [WSAETIMEDOUT ]; TIMEOUT; count 12; recommendation warn; host 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 at 60.16.182.53:9001) 
29-Jun-17 10:13:10 AM.300 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
29-Jun-17 10:13:10 AM.300 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:13:10 AM.300 [WARN]  4 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
29-Jun-17 10:13:10 AM.300 [WARN]  2 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
29-Jun-17 10:13:53 AM.000 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:13:53 AM.000 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:13:53 AM.000 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:17:16 AM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:17:16 AM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:17:16 AM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:17:16 AM.100 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:17:32 AM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (IOERROR; IOERROR; count 13; recommendation warn; host A17A40775FBD2CA1184BF80BFC330A77ECF9D0E9 at 128.105.214.163:8080) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:32 AM.300 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
29-Jun-17 10:17:32 AM.300 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
29-Jun-17 10:17:32 AM.300 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:17:32 AM.300 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host FC562097E1951DCC41B7D7F324D88157119BB56D at 128.105.214.162:8080) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:35 AM.100 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host 1E326AAFB3FCB515015250D8FCCC8E37F91A153B at 128.105.214.161:8080) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  6 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host 0E858AC201BF0F3FA3C462F64844CBFFC7297A42 at 131.252.210.150:8080) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  7 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  5 connections died in state handshaking (Tor, v3 handshake) with SSL state SSL negotiation finished successfully in OPEN 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  3 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object) 
29-Jun-17 10:17:36 AM.300 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv3 read finished A in HANDSHAKE
```

Answer (score 0):

DisableNetwork is set, you need to edit your torrc file and either comment it out, remove it or set to 0.
The biggest question is if you didnt set it manually who did and why? often disable network can be set if your time is way off. Tor needs accurate time to work and your computers system time could be off, therefore throwing the disable network. So check your torrc and remove/comment/set 0 on DisableNetwork. I would also update your time before trying to connect again, and then check to see if DisableNetwork was turned back on if you still cant.

Edit Torrc info; https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#torrc

Other info; https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#DoesntWork

Comment: No, disable network is normally set in Tor Browser while Tor Launcher decides if you're going to use bridges or not, since it doesn't want to try to connect directly to Tor if the user needs to use bridges.